# How to add more than one calendar using onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add more than one calendar in a single page by calling the javascript onclick function with jQuery-UI, does anyone know how to achieve that?

```
<script>
   function openCalander(element) {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker('slow');
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: i think you should remove `java` tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by selecting multiple elements:

```
$("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").datepicker('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onclick="ShowDtPk(this);">

<script>
function ShowDtPk(t)
{
    $(t).datepicker('slow');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Always try to include some description in your answers. Do not just drop some code with no explanation. Thanks! [will delete this comment in a while]